# Web scraping using python(BeautifulSoup and requests)

Tags: python

I am trying to **scrape** a website currently I have this
but it's **scraping** in **Html** but I need **Javascript**

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'website'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parse")
soup.findAll('a')
print(soup)
```

Comment: "but I need Javascript" -> Can you clarify what you mean? Are you trying to extract information within the JavaScript? Is JavaScript being used to render content dynamically? Is the webpage blocking access without JavasScript?

Comment: 1. I need to scarp the website as JS 2.website is not blocking I'm just scarping as htlm

Comment: It’s __scrape__ and __scraping__ not scarp or scarping